# C++ - msgsnd & msgrcv communication between 2 different programs

Tags: c++, fork, message-queue

I have two programs and I want them to communicate together by `msgrcv()` && `msgsnd()`. I so have a master program which init the message queue and start the 2 others programs:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int qid = msgget(ftok(".",'u'), 0);

  char* params[3];
  params[1] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 9);
  sprintf(params[1], "%d", qid);
  params[2] = NULL;

  printf("qid = %d and qid(str) = %s", qid, params[1]);

  //  return (0);

  //spawning two child processes
  pid_t cpid = fork();

  if (cpid == 0) {
    params[0] = (char*)"./sender";
    execv(params[0], params);
    exit(0);
  }
  cpid = fork();
  if (cpid == 0) {
    params[0] = (char*)"./receiver";
    execv(params[0],  params);
    exit(0);
  }

  while (wait(NULL) != -1); // waiting for both children to terminate

  msgctl(qid, IPC_RMID, NULL);

  std::cout << "parent proc: " << getpid()
        << " now exits" << std::endl;

  exit(0);
}
```

I also prepare the parameters and start the both following programs:

### sender

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int ac, char **av) {

  if (ac != 2)
    return (-1);

  // create my msgQ with key value from ftok()
  //  int qid = msgget(IPC_PRIVATE, IPC_EXCL|IPC_CREAT|0600);
  int qid = atoi(av[1]);
  // declare my message buffer
  struct buf {
    long mtype; // required
    char greeting[50]; // mesg content
  };

  buf msg;
  int size = sizeof(msg)-sizeof(long);

  std::cout << "Welcome in the prog assignment 2! Type [exit] to stop the program." << std::endl;

  bool exit = false;
  while (!exit)
    {
      std::cout << getpid() << ": ";
      std::cin.getline(msg.greeting, 50, '\n');
      std::cout << msg.greeting << std::endl;
      msg.mtype = 114; // only reading mesg with type mtype = 114
      if (strcmp(msg.greeting, "exit") == 0)
    exit = true;
      msgsnd(qid, (struct msgbuf *)&msg, size, 0);
    }
}
```

### receiver

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int ac, char **av) {

  int i = 0;
  while (i < ac)
    printf("AV: %s\n", av[i++]);

  if (ac != 2)
    return (-1);

  //  int qid = msgget(IPC_PRIVATE, IPC_EXCL|IPC_CREAT|0600);
  int qid = atoi(av[1]);
  // declare my message buffer
  struct buf {
    long mtype;
    char greeting[50];
  };
  buf msg;
  int size = sizeof(msg)-sizeof(long);

  bool exit = false;
  while (!exit)
    {
      msgrcv(qid, (struct msgbuf *)&msg, size, 114, 0);
      if (strcmp(msg.greeting, "exit") == 0)
    exit = true;
      std::cout << getpid() << msg.greeting << std::endl;
    }
  std::cout << "get out" << std::endl;
}
```

It doesn't work and I'm not sure to understand why because, I'm creating the message queue, passing it as parameter, then I put it back as int and then use it. However, it just gives me an infinite loop of weird display, why?

ANy help is welcome.. Thank !

Comment: It's the number the teacher used in an example, so I used it because I was using 1 and it wasn't working.. But 1 or 114 doesn't change anything anyway..

Comment: I see your logic now. sender is suppose to getline from user. Make sure that qid value is transferred to the children correctly. try to print it both in both places.

Comment: Finally got to a terminal. I think what happens here is that the receiver fails to wait. so I would suggest to 1) remove the loop. 2) do this   `int qid = msgget(ftok("a-unique-file-name-that-you-can-delete-it",'S'),0777 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL);` 3) check the return value from `msgrcv`: like this: `if (-1 == msgrcv(qid, &msg, sizeof(msg.greeting), 1, 0))
        std::cerr << "I couldnot receive :-( \n";`

Comment: Ok I will try it tonight :) thank you